# Custom 503 Error Page With Varnish

Tags: varnish

How can I tell Varnish to show a custom html error page instead of [the default "Guru Meditation" message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Guru_Meditation_Varnish_.jpg)?

Comment: Could be done with some inline C, see: http://mohanjith.net/blog/2009/08/using-custom-error-pages-in-varnish.html

Comment: Thanks, why don't you make that comment a suggested answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Varnish FAQ](http://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/faq/general.html) suggests using vcl_error for this (and it's how I've done it):

This is the default VCL for the error page:

```
sub vcl_error {
    set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";

    synthetic {"
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>"} obj.status " " obj.response {"</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Error "} obj.status " " obj.response {"</h1>
                <p>"} obj.response {"</p>
                <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
                <p>XID: "} req.xid {"</p>
                <address><a href="http://www.varnish-cache.org/">Varnish</a></address>
            </body>
        </html>
    "};
    return(deliver);
}
```

if you want a custom version, simply override the function in your config and replace the markup in the `synthetic` statement.

If you want to have different markup for different error codes you can do that fairly easily too:

```
sub vcl_error {
    set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    if (obj.status == 404) {
        synthetic {"
            <!-- Markup for the 404 page goes here -->
        "};
    } else if (obj.status == 500) {
        synthetic {"
            <!-- Markup for the 500 page goes here -->
        "};
    } else {
        synthetic {"
            <!-- Markup for a generic error page goes here -->
        "};
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not work in VCL 4.0 - if you use vcl 4.0 then see answer below

Answer (score 21):

Note that the above answers are for Varnish 3. As the question does not not specify version information, it seems an appropriate time to include the answer for Version 4 also as it has changed.

Hopefully this will save people from reading the above answers and putting vcl_error into their V4 VCL :)

**Builtin VCL for Varnish 4.0**

```
sub vcl_synth {
    set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set resp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    synthetic( {"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>"} + resp.status + " " + resp.reason + {"</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error "} + resp.status + " " + resp.reason + {"</h1>
    <p>"} + resp.reason + {"</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
"} );
    return (deliver);
}
```

Note also that if you want to throw an error from within your VCL, you no longer use the 'error' function, instead you would do:

```
return (synth(405));
```

Also, 413, 417 and 503 errors from the backend are autmatically routed through this funtion.

Comment: Please note that this will not capture "backend fetch errors". To capture them, you must also create a `sub vcl_backend_error`, as you can see in http://serverfault.com/a/665917/102757 and http://serverfault.com/a/716767/102757