# Change varnish 4 503 error

Tags: varnish

How can i change varnish 503 error?
How can i customize it ?
i'm using varnish v 4

it's now work

```
sub vcl_synth {
    set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    set resp.http.Retry-After = "5";
    synthetic( {"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Under Maintenance</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Under Maintenance</h1>
    <p></p>
    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
"} );
    return (deliver);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two kinds of errors in Varnish 4.
One is backend fetch errors.`vcl_backend_error` handles this kind of errors.
Another is errors generated in VCL. `vcl_synth` handles this kind of errors.

In your case, you're customizing `vcl_error` subroutine, that is not for backend errors.

You can distinguish these two kinds of erros from following default.vcl.

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/404") {
        return (synth(999, "make 404 error explicitly"));
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
}

sub vcl_deliver {
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
    set beresp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    synthetic( {"errors due to backend fetch"} );
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 999) {
        set resp.status = 404;
        set resp.http.Content-Type = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        synthetic({"errors due to vcl"});
        return (deliver);
    }
    return (deliver);
}
```

Confirm error messages

```
$ curl http://localhost:6081/   # If the backend server is not running, "503 Backend fetch failed" error occurs 
errors due to backend fetch
$ curl http://localhost:6081/404/foo
errors due to vcl
```

Answer (score 15):

I would like to propose an alternative... please find below a sample default.vcl file

```
vcl 4.0;

import std;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
       if (beresp.status == 503 && bereq.retries < 5 ) {
       return(retry);
 }
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
      if (beresp.status == 503 && bereq.retries == 5) {
          synthetic(std.fileread("/etc/varnish/error503.html"));
          return(deliver);
       }
 }

sub vcl_synth {
    if (resp.status == 503) {
        synthetic(std.fileread("/etc/varnish/error503.html"));
        return(deliver);
     }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.status == 503) {
        return(restart);
    }
  }
```

And then you can save your custom html in error503.html